# Getting a UIImage from an ALASSET to use ad an attachment when sending an email

Tags: ios, iphone, email, uiimage, alassetslibrary

I have a collection view which contains ALASSETS, I want to be able to select an item (photo) in the collection view and send it as an attachment in an email.
The collection view is based on a tutorial, iPhone Programming Tutorial: Creating An Image Gallery this is a recent post so it should be up to date.

The code executed when the user selects a photo is as follows.

```
-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView         didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`enter code here`(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
 ALAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
 ALAssetRepresentation *defaultRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[defaultRep fullScreenImage] scale:[defaultRep scale] orientation:0];



[self.testImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[defaultRep fullScreenImage] scale:[defaultRep scale] orientation:0]];
[self.testImage2 setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]]];

// send email
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"rasmus4200@gmail.com"]];
    [controller setSubject:@"Subject Goes Here."];
    [controller setMessageBody:@"Your message goes here." isHTML:NO];

    // Attach an image to the email
    //NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(coolImage);
    //NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]], 1.0);
    NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    [controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"coolImage.jpg"];

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email in its current state.");
}
```

The important lines of code would seem to be .

I should now have an image which I can pass to the email as an attachment as follows

```
NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

But when I view my email there is no image.

I thought maybe I was not actually getting the asset so i did the following test
I decided to include the asset thumbnail image as follows which is now commented

```
NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]], 1.0);
```

and this works fine it created the email with the thumbnail

This problem has me tearing my hair out so any help will be gratefully accepted.

I have tried the following in many shapes and forms to retrieve the image but nothing seems to work

Attempt 1 :

```
// Set up Blocks
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *asset)
{
    UIImage *coolImage;

    // get the image
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        coolImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
    }

    // send email
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"rasmus4200@gmail.com"]];
        [controller setSubject:@"Subject Goes Here."];
        [controller setMessageBody:@"Your message goes here." isHTML:NO];

        // Attach an image to the email
        //NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(coolImage);
        NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(coolImage, 1.0);
        [controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"coolImage.jpg"];

        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email in its current state.");
    }
};


ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"booya, cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};



// GET THE URL of image
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] init];
url = asset.defaultRepresentation.url;

// create library and set callbacks
ALAssetsLibrary *al = [ConDetailsViewController defaultAssetsLibrary];
[al assetForURL:url
    resultBlock:resultblock
   failureBlock:failureblock];

}
```

Comment: Is `self.testImage` a UIImageView? If so, are you seeing the resulting image from calling `-setImage:`?

Comment: Yes but I only put it in to test the image returned by         [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[defaultRep fullScreenImage] scale:[defaultRep scale] orientation:0]; its blank

Comment: I believe then that `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[defaultRep fullScreenImage] scale:[defaultRep scale] orientation:0]` is returning `nil`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is, the value returned is nil

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for your help to date , I have made another post on the same subject which explains the problem more simply I hope "Unable to get image from collection view"

Comment: whats the size of image that you are loading?